# Get server IP address

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is there a way to get the Sharepoint server's IP address? 
This code below just retrieves the hostname but I need to know the IP address.

```
string hostName = SPServer.Local.Address;
```

Comment: WHich programming language are we talking about?

Comment: C# with Sharepoint 2010.

Comment: If you always only have the hostname, see here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/get-ip-address-from-dns-hostname-in-c/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a host name you can get the IP address of the host by using [Dns.GetHostEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the `System.Net` namespace.

You can get the first IPv4 address of a host name using this code:

```
var ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName)
  .AddressList
  .First(ipAddress => ipAddress.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
```

The code will throw exceptions if either the host is unknown or if it doesn't have an IPv4 address.

Answer (score 0):

SPServer has a member named 'SPServer.Address', if this isn't the value you are looking for then maybe try through HttpRequest.UserHostAccess